# sed /end-of-line$/ pattern matching not working with shell variable which contain / in variable value

Tags: bash, sed

Variable declared

```
var1=/home/jrajpal/sync_dir
var2=/test/
```

Example of my input file

```
cat test.txt
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test1/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test1

sed "s#$var1#& $var2#2" /home/jrajpal/test.txt
```

When run above command to search for exact pattern and replace with, it's catching for all 3 lines and replacing, whereas I need to match only first line from file but end-of-line$ pattern not working

`sed "s#$var1\$#& $var2#2" /home/jrajpal/test.txt`   - - > This command not doing as expected and file output remain same

```
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test
/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test1/ server1.example.com:/rsync/LegADC-LLG02_dst/home/jrajpal/sync_dir/test1
```

Comment: Can you post a hex dump of your input file (e.g. from `xxd test.txt`)?

Comment: @Jitu, comments are NOT meant for posting samples, please edit your post with adding samples and covering them in code tags.

Comment: That looks mangled. The bytes are swapped or something. How did you produce that dump?

Comment: I used unix command hexdump /home/jrajpal/test.txt which generated output

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I am sorry, I am not sure how to put sample in code tags, new on this

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "s#$var1\$#& $var2#2"
#                      ^
```

The problem is that `2` at the end. It tells `sed` to only replace the second match in each line.

But `$` only matches at the end of a line, so this pattern can only match once per line to begin with.

In other words, you're telling sed to look for the second end of each line, which makes no sense.

```
sed "s#$var1\$#& $var2#"
```

should fix it.